# How to quickly find sum of all pairs of elements in 2 different arrays

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, big-o

So recently I hit upon this programming problem which I couldn't seem to make the complexity less (my current code runs in O(n^2)).

Essentially, I have four different lists (I'm using python btw) of integers, both positive and negative, say lists A, B, C, D. Now, each of these lists has 1000 integers, and these integers range from -25000 to 25000 inclusive. Now, suppose from each of these lists we choose an integer, say a, b, c, d. I would like the quickest way to find these a, b, c, d such that a+b=-(c+d).

Currently, my method relies on iterating through every single possible combination of a, b, and c, d, before then trying to find if an element in the set (a+b) exists in the set -(c+d). This, of course, is impractical since it runs in O(n^2) time, even more so considering the large list sizes (1000).

Hence I was wondering if anyone could think of a more efficient way (preferably O(n log n) or smaller), coded in python if possible.

Apologies if it's rather confusing. If you have any questions please inform me, I'll try to provide more clarification.

EDIT:

This problem is part of a larger problem. The larger problem states that if we have 4 sequences of numbers with at most 1000 integers in each,  say A, B, C, D, find an a, b, c, d such that a+b+c+d=0.

I asked the above question since a+b+c+d=0 implies that a+b=-(c+d), which I thought would lead to the fastest way to solve the problem. If anyone can think of an even faster way, please do share it with me.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: are you looking for ALL combinations that apply to that condition ?

Comment: Yes, that is so. It is assured that there will be at least 1 such combination.

Comment: In the worst case, when C = -A and D = -B, you'll have Θ(n^2) solutions, so your algorithm will need at least n^2 steps to produce that output.

Comment: Hmm if that's the case then perhaps this algorithm for solving the larger problem is wrong...I'll go and provide more context.

Comment: One thing you can try is sort the lists and use that criteria to search for elements in other two arrays. This might help you to get O(nlogn) solution.

Comment: Hmm could you explain further? I'm afraid I don't quite see the correlation between sorting the list and increasing efficiency. Thanks.

Comment: essentially you are trying to find a pair (a+b) which is -(c+d), so instead of getting all the pairs (a,b), if you sort the lists you can do binary search on the lists to find such pairs .. say you have c+d as 10, and first element in list  A is 2 then all you need to find in list B is 8 .. but we need to think more to get (c+d) from sorted list as well ..

Comment: Ah I see...that seems like an interesting method which should work once we manage to get the (c+d) efficiently. Nevertheless, thank you for that interesting insight!

Comment: This question is similar to finding four elements in an array having certain sum. The best case algorithm is to get all the pairs of elements in A and B, and the complexity cannot go beyond O(n^2). This link might give an explanation for with the code: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-four-elements-that-sum-to-a-given-value-set-2/, http://code.cloudkaksha.org/arrays/four-elements-sum-given-value-array

Comment: Also, the complexity for looking up an element in set is O(1) average case and O(n) worst case. So, the algorithm which you are using has worst case complexity of O(n^3)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem isn't that combining pairs of elements is O(n^2), but rather the fact that you're combining two such processes naively to end up with an O(n^4) algorithm. I'm going to assume you just need to find >= 1 ways to add up to 0 -- my method given below can easily be extended to find *all* ways, if it's required.

Given that you have a relatively narrow range of accepted values (-25k to +25k, let's call those MIN and MAX respectively), here's what you do:

Create 2 int arrays of size (MAX - MIN + 1), "indicesA" and "indicesB". That's not even 0.5 MB of memory all together, so nothing to worry about on a modern system.

Now loop on all elements of lists A and B, just like you were doing. Do something like this pseudo-code (not too familiar with python so I'm not sure if it's valid as-is):

```
for idxA, valA in enumerate(A):
    for idxB, valB in enumerate(B):
        indicesA[valA + valB - MIN] = idxA + 1
        indicesB[valA + valB - MIN] = idxB + 1
```

Now just use this as an O(1) lookup-table when looping on B and C:

```
for valC in C:
    for valD in D:
        neededVal = -(valC + valD) - MIN
        if indicesA[neededVal] > 0:
            print('Found solution: {0} {1} {2} {3}'.format(A[indicesA[neededVal] - 1], 
                 B[indicesB[neededVal] - 1], valC, valD))
```

- Lookup-table initialization with 0s: O(MAX - MIN) (~50k, smaller than n^2 in this case)
- Filling lookup-table by looping on A and B: O(n^2)
- Looping on C and D and checking for any solutions: O(n^2)

Overall, O(n^2 + (MAX - MIN)) =~ O(n^2) with the values given. Probably can't do much better than that.

Answer (score 0):

You have four arrays and you want to choose one number from each array, such that the sum of the four numbers is zero. The technical name for this problem is 4SUM×4.

This problem is at least as hard [3SUM×3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM#3_different_arrays), where three numbers summing to zero must be chosen from three arrays. An instance of 3SUM×3 can be converted to an instance of 4SUM×4 by simply adding an array of zeros. So any algorithm solving your problem can be used to solve 3SUM×3 in the same time complexity.

It doesn't appear to be known for certain that 3SUM×3 isn't easier than the more famous [3SUM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM) problem, but it seems very likely to be equally difficult. A 3SUM×3 algorithm can be used to solve the 3SUM problem or [determine with arbitrarily high probability](https://math.aurelienooms.be/2016/04/27/equivalence-of-3sum-problems/) that no solution exists. (The only issue with reducing 3SUM to 3SUM×3 is that 3SUM×3 allows solutions like `1, 1, -2` whereas 3SUM doesn't.) The theoretically-best known algorithms for 3SUM only beat O(n<sup>2</sup>) by factors of (log n) to some power.

Given all of that, it seems very unlikely that your problem can be solved in significantly less than O(n<sup>2</sup>) time, asymptotically.